# Partially blurred screen

Tags: screen

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and my screen is sometimes blurred as on the picture.

It sometimes disappears after restart and sometimes it appears again.

Do you know what is the cause of this problem and how to fix it?

[image]

One picture again (the pattern changes)
[image]

```
$ lspci -nnk
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 82852/82855 GM/GME/PM/GMV Processor to I/O Controller [8086:3580] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0064]
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel
00:00.1 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation 82852/82855 GM/GME/PM/GMV Processor to I/O Controller [8086:3584] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0064]
00:00.3 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation 82852/82855 GM/GME/PM/GMV Processor to I/O Controller [8086:3585] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0064]
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82852/82855 GM/GME/PM/GMV Processor to AGP Controller [8086:3581] (rev 02)
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:24c2] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0064]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:24c4] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0064]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:24c7] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0064]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-M) USB2 EHCI Controller [8086:24cd] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0064]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev 83)
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801DBM (ICH4-M) LPC Interface Bridge [8086:24cc] (rev 03)
    Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt, intel-rng
00:1f.1 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801DBM (ICH4-M) IDE Controller [8086:24ca] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0064]
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) SMBus Controller [8086:24c3] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0064]
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801
00:1f.5 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Audio Controller [8086:24c5] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0064]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_intel8x0
    Kernel modules: snd-intel8x0
00:1f.6 Modem [0703]: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Modem Controller [8086:24c6] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0064]
    Kernel modules: snd-intel8x0m
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV350 [Mobility Radeon 9600 M10] [1002:4e50]
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0064]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon, radeonfb
02:02.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401 100Base-T [14e4:4401] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0064]
    Kernel driver in use: b44
    Kernel modules: b44
02:04.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] Network Connection [8086:4220] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2701]
    Kernel driver in use: ipw2200
    Kernel modules: ipw2200
02:06.0 CardBus bridge [0607]: Texas Instruments PCIxx21/x515 Cardbus Controller [104c:8031]
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0064]
    Kernel driver in use: yenta_cardbus
    Kernel modules: yenta_socket
02:06.2 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: Texas Instruments OHCI Compliant IEEE 1394 Host Controller [104c:8032]
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0064]
    Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
    Kernel modules: firewire-ohci
02:06.3 Mass storage controller [0180]: Texas Instruments PCIxx21 Integrated FlashMedia Controller [104c:8033]
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0064]
    Kernel driver in use: tifm_7xx1
    Kernel modules: tifm_7xx1
$ sudo dpkg -l '*mesa*'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                              Version                           Description
+++-=================================-=================================-==================================================================================
ii  libgl1-mesa-dev                   8.0.4-0ubuntu0.6                  free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX development files
un  libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-quantal       <none>                            (no description available)
un  libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-raring        <none>                            (no description available)
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri                   8.0.4-0ubuntu0.4                  free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
un  libgl1-mesa-dri-dev               <none>                            (no description available)
un  libgl1-mesa-dri-experimental      <none>                            (no description available)
ii  libgl1-mesa-glx                   8.0.4-0ubuntu0.6                  free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
un  libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal       <none>                            (no description available)
un  libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-raring        <none>                            (no description available)
un  libgl1-mesa-glx-no-multiarch      <none>                            (no description available)
un  libgl1-mesa-swx11-dev             <none>                            (no description available)
ii  libglapi-mesa                     8.0.4-0ubuntu0.6                  free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libglu1-mesa                      8.0.4-0ubuntu0.6                  Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
ii  libglu1-mesa-dev                  8.0.4-0ubuntu0.6                  Mesa OpenGL utility library -- development files
ii  mesa-common-dev                   8.0.4-0ubuntu0.6                  Developer documentation for Mesa
un  mesa-common-dev-lts-quantal       <none>                            (no description available)
un  mesa-common-dev-lts-raring        <none>                            (no description available)
un  mesa-glide2-dev                   <none>                            (no description available)
ii  mesa-utils                        8.0.1+git20110129+d8f7d6b-0ubuntu Miscellaneous Mesa GL utilities
un  mesag-dev                         <none>                            (no description available)
un  mesag3                            <none>                            (no description available)
un  mesag3+ggi-dev                    <none>                            (no description available)
un  xlibmesa-dev                      <none>                            (no description available)
un  xlibmesa-dri                      <none>                            (no description available)
un  xlibmesa-gl-dev                   <none>                            (no description available)
un  xlibmesa-glu-dev                  <none>                            (no description available)
un  xlibmesa3                         <none>                            (no description available)
un  xlibosmesa-dev                    <none>                            (no description available)
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `lspci -nnk` from a terminal window.

Comment: @mikewhatever I pasted it to the question.

Comment: Have you made some update to graphic drivers recently?

Comment: Does this happen only with this OS? Is it possible to check if the issue is there with windows?

Comment: Just for clarity, is the above a picture of the screen taken by a camera device, or its an actual screenshot of the screen??

Comment: @Danibix No, I haven't

Comment: @daltonfury42 I'm using only Ubuntu.

Comment: @Kelvinelove This is a partial screenshot of the screen (taken with `scrot -s`)

Comment: @xralf What browser is this?

Comment: @xralf And does it happen in any application or just in this particular browser?

Comment: @xralf And last question - what's the version of `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package on your system? And output of `dpkg -l '*mesa*'`. Are you by any chance using any PPAs with updated drivers?

Comment: @oerdnj The screenshots are from Firefox, but it's not only browser problem.

Comment: @oerdnj `dpkg -l '*mesa*'` is pasted already in the question

Comment: I've seen similar glitches when my video card was dying. Try booting a live CD/USB a few times (perhaps even not an Ubuntu one) and see if the problem occurs. If it does, this is a hardware problem.

Comment: How much RAM and swap space do you have on your setup? I've seen people on very low-RAM systems have graphical glitches similar to yours, which clear up when they put in additional RAM.

Comment: to add to my comment above: If you are indeed running Ubuntu on a very low-RAM system, switching to a lighter-weight desktop environment, such as the one in Lubuntu, might be an alternative to installing more RAM.

Comment: @NickWeinberg I have 2GB RAM. I restarted the laptop and the problem is not present now, without doing nothing, but it may appear again. These are the problems that are difficult to diagnose, what is the cause.